# How do I prove the following lemma in Coq?

Tags: coq

```
Lemma rev_firstn : forall (x : list bool) (n : nat),
rev (firstn n x) = firstn n (rev x).
```

I have spent quite a bit of time on this. I start out with a sensible goal but always end up with a goal that is impossible to prove.

Here is my current approach:

```
Proof.
  intros. generalize dependent x. induction n. 
  + easy. 
  + induction x.
    - easy. 
    -
```

In my context, I now have:

```
IHn : forall x : list bool, rev (firstn n x) = firstn n (rev x)
IHx : rev (firstn (S n) x) = firstn (S n) (rev x)
```

and my goal is:

```
rev (firstn (S n) (a :: x)) = firstn (S n) (rev (a :: x))
```

Is there a way to generalize x in IHx so that I can specialize it to 
(a :: x)? Since I don't know the right tactic to do this, I try the following, and end up with the previously mentioned impossible goal.

```
Proof.
  intros. generalize dependent x. induction n. 
  + easy. 
  + induction x.
    - easy. 
    - assert (rev_cons : forall (b : bool) (l : list bool), 
              rev (b :: l) = rev l ++ [b]).
      { easy. } rewrite firstn_cons. 
      rewrite rev_cons. rewrite rev_cons. specialize (@IHn x).
      rewrite IHn.
Goal: firstn n (rev x) ++ [a] = firstn (S n) (rev x ++ [a])
```

This goal is impossible because for n = 0 and rev x = h :: t, the goal 
reduces to `[a] = List.hd (rev (h :: t)) ++ [a]`.

Is this lemma actually unsound, or am I just missing some tactics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `firstn` and `rev` are what I think they are, I don't think the lemma is true.

```
rev (firstn 2 [true, false, false])
= rev [true, false]
= [false, true]
```

but

```
firstn 2 (rev [true, false, false])
= firstn 2 [false, false, true]
= [false, false]
```

Essentially, `rev (firstn n x)` is the first `n` elements of `x` (in reverse order), but `firstn n (rev x)` is the last `n` elements of `x` (also in reverse order). For this lemma to be true in any sort of generality, you would need x to have at most `n` elements. As Arthur Azevedo De Amorim notes in the comments, you can also get a correct version of this lemma if you insert a `skipn n` to just look at the last `n` (at most) elements of `x`.

`rev (firstn n (skipn (length x - n)) x) = firstn n (rev x)`

Comment: The correct statement should be something like `firstn n (rev x) = rev (skipn (length x  - n) x)`.

Comment: It is proved in mathcomp's `seq` library (where the functions are called `take`, `drop`, and `size`, instead of `firstn`, `skipn`, and `length`).

Comment: You're right. I'm making it a habit of stating these unsound statements in my head and putting a lot of effort into proving them before thinking about them. I guess that's one utility of Coq :). Thank you guys!